# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Swift Kohana Framework Email Swiftmailer

Tags: php, email, frameworks, kohana, swiftmailer

I installed Kohan Email module from http://github.com/banks/kohana-email to my Kohana Frameword and when I'm trying to register on my website I get following issue:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Swift in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\biblioteka\modules\email\vendor\swift\classes\Swift.php on line 29
```

I used following codes to send an email:

```
Email::send('example1@gmail.com', 'example2@gmail.com', 'tittle', 'content');
```

and

```
require Kohana::find_file('vendor', 'swift/swift_required', 'php');
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465);
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Email')
        ->setFrom(array('example1@gmail.com' => 'From'))
        ->setTo(array('example2@gmail.com'))
        ->setBody('An email');
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

There's the same problem for boths of codes.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be directly including any swift files from the vendor directory, or instantiating any swift classes.

As long as you have the following line in your `bootstrap.php` file, the necessary files will be included from the vendor directory by the email module.

```
Kohana::modules(array(
    // Other modules here...
    'email'      => MODPATH.'email',         // Email
));
```

The reason you're getting an error telling you you've already declared swift, is because you have (via the email module).

You then just send emails using your first example (`Email` class only):

```
Email::send('example1@gmail.com', 'example2@gmail.com', 'tittle', 'content');
```